# If cell contains text in a range of values, return adjacent value of text found

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm looking for a way to go down a range (A2-A5) to see if any of the cells contain a value that a specific string (D2) contains. Once it does that, it'll return the cell to the right of the cell (B) with the text contained in the specific string (D2).

Here's an example, where the output is located in E2 to the cell to search (D2):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYHQq.jpg]

The most similar solution would be:

```
OFFSET(INDEX(A2:A5,MATCH("*"&D2&"*",A2:A5,0)),0,1)
```

but this only accounts for exact matches. What I'm looking for is for this to check the cell if it contains any of the strings in A2-A5, not if it matches any of the string exactly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi BigBen, Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D2:D, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A))), A2:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]